# Python 3 variable scoping (2 test cases): Is y4 a local variable? Is y4 being referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

The following code was more unpredictable than I had expected.

Test case 1:

```
# Line with print is OK:

y4 = 0    

def G6():
    print(f"y4={y4}")

G6()
```

Output:
y4=0

Test case 2:

```
# Line with print throws error this time:
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y5' referenced before assignment
# But why exactly? If y5 is a local variable, then y4 (above) should be too, IMO.
# Is y4 (above) even a local variable? Is y4 (above) also being referenced before assignment, or not?

y5 = 0    

def G7():
    print(f"y5={y5}")
    y5 += 2

G7()
```

Output on the line print():
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y5' referenced before assignment

Can this python behavior be rationalized?

Comment: Names are local **when bound to in a function**. So `y5` is local because you assigned to it, and assignment is a binding action. See [*Naming and Binding*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding)

Comment: Also see the duplicate, the top answer defines local as: *L, Local — Names assigned in any way within a function (def or lambda)), and not declared global in that function.*

Comment: Why does line with print throw error, but not line with the reading of y5?  This is the gist of my question.

Comment: Because `y5` is a local variable in `G7`, and you can't use one variable both as a local and a global in the same scope. Python determines the scope *at compile time*, not at runtime, `y5` is a local variable because you assign to it with `y5 += 2`, making **all** references to `y5` inside `G7` a local variable. When you try to print `y5` nothing has been assigned to it yet.

Comment: Thank you.  Now notice that 0 was assigned to y5 as the first line of code. Why can't the function read y5?

Comment: Because it is *not the same variable*. `y5` is assigned to in the global scope so it is a global. Variables have scope and a name, for you to access a given variable you need to match both. If you want `y5` inside a function to be seen as a global, *and* you want to bind to it, you must tell the Python compiler so explicitly with `global y5`.